# How do I solve these problems? ERROR: Could not find a version

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\isato\Desktop>pip install ImageDataGenerator

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imageDataGenerator (from version: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ImageDataGenerator
```

How do I solve ? Thank you for your understanding!

Comment: What is the name of the library you wanna install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use **ImageDataGenerator** as a standalone module, while it's actually a part of **Keras**, so you have to install **Keras** to be able to use **Keras**'s module **ImageDatagenerator**.

Install **Keras** and import **Imagedatagenerator** using **pip** or **pip3** in your code

without **GPU**:

```
pip install tensorflow keras
```

with **GPU**:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu keras
```

This assumes you already have **conda** installed, alternatively you might need to install OS-level dependencies - for example for Ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you want to install a new package use the [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/) website to check it.

https://pypi.org/project/h5imagegenerator/ This is probably the module you're trying to install. if you ever get the same error just google the module name followed by PyPI so it will give you the PyPI link and it will show you the exact name of the name used to install the module.